# Java, converting ArrayList to array (toArray) cannot be casted?

Tags: java

there is Depot:

```
public class Depot
{
    private final int x, y;

    public Depot(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Im making a list of it:

```
ArrayList<Depot> depots = new ArrayList<>();
depots.add(new Depot(1, 2));
depots.add(new Depot(5, 7));
```

and they has to be passed to another method:

```
Object[] d2 = depots.toArray();
op((Depot[]) d2); ****

public void op(Depot[] depots)
```

but the **** row triggers an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Depot;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below to get the array of same type as List

```
    List<Depot> depts = new ArrayList<Depot>();
    depts.add(new Depot(1, 2));
    depts.add(new Depot(1, 2));
    depts.add(new Depot(1, 2));
    Depot[] depots = depts.toArray(new Depot[depts.size()]);
```